# How to integrate a standalone Qt project into a C++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, dialog, program-entry-point

I have a Qt standalone project developed on Mac by Qt C++ code, which upon double click or ./qtProject, pops up a dialog box. (The dialog collects value from the input line edit slots)

The standalone Qt application has its own makefile and main function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    DsnDialog dsndialog;
    dsndialog.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

In my C++ project, when I have a function configFn() called, then I want to initialize the dialog box. How should I do that? My c++ project requires compiling shared library files. Should I move the generated .o files form the Qt project into the makefile in my c++ project? I tried that but it complains cannot find the corresponding .cc files related to the new added .o files...

I also tried, to rename the main function and then call the renamed-main function from another function, but I do not know how to deal with the arguments in the main function, argc, argv

Any suggestions or links I could explore please?

EDIT:
I am more confused now. Usually, do I put the whole Qt project, deploy in a bundle, include in my project as a library and then call to run the application? Or there is someway which I could just run the generated application to pop up the window?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You cannot create any Dialog or widget without calling an instance of QApplication. You can pack the dialog into a shared library, but later, creating the dialog would require a valid QApplication to run. Moving object files to C++ projects won't help cause they also need Qt's DLLs and headers. Such step would make the whole thing a mess.

Comment: @Md.MinhazulHaque : Thank you for your reply. I tried to include the Qt libraries in the makefile CPPFLAGS, and I added -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/ However, there're 4 folders named, bin, include, lib, plugins under directory Qt4.8.6 When I try to build the program, it could find the dialog.h file, but could find the #include <QWidget>, which is the header of the dialog.h file. Do you have any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: I am also confused now, hehe. I suggest you to go for Qt 5.4.1 which is released several days ago.

I read your previous question. I think you are trying to run the Qt project from another C++ project right? You can try `open ~/project/p.app` from your C++ program which will run the app without clicking with Finder or cd'ing into `p.app/Content/MacOS/`.

AFAIK, you can't bind two application contexts. You better "execute" the app separately.